WPF Path mouse over trigger in style
I am using a DataTemplateSelector to select DataTemplates for ListBox items based on an enum value.
public class MenuBarDataTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        DataTemplate template = null;

        var element = container as FrameworkElement;


        MenuItemModel model = (MenuItemModel)item;
        switch (model.ItemType)
        {
            case MenuItemType.Home:
                template = element.FindResource("MenuItemHome") as DataTemplate;
                break;

            case MenuItemType.Contacts:
                template = element.FindResource("MenuItemContacts") as DataTemplate;
                break;
        }

        return template;
    }
}

Each data template has a Path to show an icon, and a TextBlock. The only difference between them is the Path to show the image is different based on the enum.
The ListBox's ItemContainerStyle has a trigger to handle the IsMouseOver affect to change the foreground color, which I can see change when I mouse over the list item. The Path style at the top also has a similar trigger, but it only changes color if the mouse is over the path itself.
<UserControl.Resources>

    <cls:MenuBarDataTemplateSelector x:Key="menuTemplateSelecor"/>

    <Style x:Key="pathStyle" 
           TargetType="{x:Type Path}">

        <Setter Property="Height" Value="22" />
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="22" />
        <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Gray" />
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
        <Setter Property="Stretch" Value="Fill" />
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5" />

        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Fill" Value="SteelBlue"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
        
    </Style>
    
    <DataTemplate x:Key="MenuItemHome">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">

            <Path x:Name="path" 
                  Data="{StaticResource homeIcon}"
                  Style="{StaticResource pathStyle}"/>

            <TextBlock Text="{Binding MenuItemName}"
                       FontSize="14"
                       VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="MenuItemContacts">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">

            <Path x:Name="path" 
                  Data="{StaticResource personIcon}"
                  Style="{StaticResource pathStyle}"/>

            <TextBlock Text="{Binding MenuItemName}"
                       FontSize="14"
                       VerticalAlignment="Center"/>

        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>

</UserControl.Resources>

<Grid>

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <ListBox Grid.Row="0"
             ItemsSource="{Binding MenuItems}"
             SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedMenuItem}"
             ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource menuTemplateSelecor}">

        <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="3"/>
                <Setter Property="Height" Value="40"/>

                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Blue"/>
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Tan"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
                
            </Style>
        </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>

    </ListBox>

</Grid>

This seems like I have the right code in the wrong places. What's the right way to do this?


change MouseOver Trigger to StackPanel: This will ensure the entire ListBoxItem responds to hover events.
Handle Path Hover Using Code Behind: Use MouseEnter and MouseLeave events to change the Path color on hover.

in your xml:
<DataTemplate x:Key="MenuItemHome">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" MouseEnter="OnMouseEnter" MouseLeave="OnMouseLeave">
        <Path x:Name="path" Data="{StaticResource homeIcon}" Fill="Gray" Height="22" Width="22" Margin="5"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding MenuItemName}" FontSize="14"/>
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate x:Key="MenuItemContacts">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" MouseEnter="OnMouseEnter" MouseLeave="OnMouseLeave">
        <Path x:Name="path" Data="{StaticResource personIcon}" Fill="Gray" Height="22" Width="22" Margin="5"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding MenuItemName}" FontSize="14"/>
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>

in your C#:
private void OnMouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    var stackPanel = sender as StackPanel;
    var path = stackPanel?.Children.OfType<Path>().FirstOrDefault();
    if (path != null)
        path.Fill = Brushes.SteelBlue;
}

private void OnMouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    var stackPanel = sender as StackPanel;
    var path = stackPanel?.Children.OfType<Path>().FirstOrDefault();
    if (path != null)
        path.Fill = Brushes.Gray;
}


I'm using MVVM, not code behind. There has to be a XAML way to do this.
